# Can the Eclipse code style formatter align assignment statements?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, code-formatting

Eclipse has an option in Indentation: "Alignment of fields in class declarations" that will
align assignments of class members as in:

```
class Foo {  
   int x    = 3;  
   String y = "abc"  
   long z   = 2;  
}
```

Is there a setting that will do the same for method level assignments as in:

```
private void foo() {  
   int x    = 3;  
   String y = "abc"  
   long z   = 2;  
}
```

I can not find such a setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Java Code Style Formatter profile (Window->Prefernces->Java->Code Style->Formatter) or modifying an older one and check Indentation and Braces tabs.

Comment: Have you set this new profile as the active one for your project specific (if it's project specific) settings?

Comment: Yes, I can see the effects of the formatter, I'm just looking for a capability that appears not to be available.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors.

There is no such option in Eclipse, but, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957139/2725790), you can use plugin named [OCDFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957139/2725790) that aligns assignments and declarations in a selected piece of code.

- Installation: download the latest version of OCDFormat_*.jar from [project page on github](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat) (click → Raw → Save as) and add it to your Eclipse plugins or dropins directory.
- Usage: select a piece of code and press Ctrl+4.

Comment: [OCDFormat](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/) is pretty good but [has an issue with some (common) operators](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/issues/5) :/

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse code style formatter cannot align assignment statements.

[columns4eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/) is plug-in that allows you to do so. I had made a gif video illustrating its use but my answer got deleted by a moderator (as >10k users will see), so I let you try the plug-in and see by yourself.