# Auto-align "=" in assignments

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, variable-assignment

How do one convert a block of variable assignments, e.g.:

```java
private final String s1 = "10011";
private final String s2 = "01100";
private final String ones = "11111";
private final String zeros = "00000";
```

To a straightened format where all `=` signs are aligned to one space after the longest left-hand side, e.g.:

```java
private final String s1    = "10011";
private final String s2    = "01100";
private final String ones  = "11111";
private final String zeros = "00000";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Preferences** → **Java** → **Code Style** → **Formatter** → goto **Edit** and check the `Align fields in columns`:

[image: Align fields in columns]

Comment: +1 Thanks. Is there a way to use spaces for alignment, while still using tabs for block indentation?

Comment: OK, got it - I should use mixed tab policy with "Use spaces to indent wrapped lines"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to align assignments and not only field declarations, this plugin does an excellent job: [OCDFormat](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/).

It works in all text files, not only java.

Comment: Sadly the blog is not available to public, hence the plugin isn't available (to me at least..). Could you provide another way to download the plugin? Thanks!

Comment: Nice but there is an issue with some (common) operators: https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/issues/5

Comment: Note that the plugin does not integrate with the formatter, so is you use the formatter it will undo the formatting done by this plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Eclipse plugin [columns4eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/):

- gratis
- open source
- I've tested it with Eclipse 4.3 x64 and 4.5 x64 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

[image]

Comment: @darkangel what's the issue with pdt?

Comment: The menu items are all disabled.

Answer (score 1):

[EclipseFormatter](https://github.com/Comee/EclipseFormatter) solved this problem perfectly which supports align fields, assignments and variable declarations in columns.

Comment: Cool! I do not use Eclipse anymore, but it's great to see an answer to a 7 years old question!