# formatting assignment blocks

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Hi i am using eclipse and pydev.

```
        self.ab  = ''
        self.acdf     = ''
        self.xcvderg         = ''
        self.a        = ''
        self.sd_file       = ''
        self._file       = ''
```

Is there any short cut that, I can format above code like below? In existing code, Many places the assignment block looks like below. Do programmers do it manually while writing code?

```
        self.ab       = ''
        self.acdf     = ''
        self.xcvderg  = ''
        self.a        = ''
        self.sd_file  = ''
        self._file    = ''
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Auto-align "=" in assignments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936569/eclipse-auto-align-in-assignments)

Comment: Possible duplicate is for Java, not sure if pydev has the same setting

Comment: I couldn't find it in pydev. I changed the perspective to java and than tried ctrl + shift + F and still it does not align in column mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in PyDev.

If you want, you can create a feature request for it at: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/