# Make code organized and good looking in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In `Sublime Text` there is a plugin that allows to make a code organized and good looking using a keyboard shortcut :

Before alignment :

[image]

After alignment :

[image]

I Googled about it, and all I can found is to inline the code using `Source-->Format`.

Isn't there any plugin in `Eclipse` that can do the same as the `Sublime Text`'s plugin ?

Comment: looks like your answer has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936569/eclipse-auto-align-in-assignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that a solution has been presented in the comments but here is an alternative.

Go to **Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->SaveActions** and enable the Format source code option. This will format the code every time you save the file.

Another way to format would be to use the shortcut of the method you described: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.