# Java code alignment tool?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there an Eclipse or command-line tool for column-aligning similar lines of Java code to make symmetry clearer?

What I've found:

- [CodeAlignment.com](http://codealignment.com/Details.html): an example of the formatting I'm looking for, but specific to Visual Studio or Notepad++.
- Eclipse built-in code formatter: aligns only equal signs, and only in field declarations.
- [columns4eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/): old, can't get it to work, but looks more like a column selection primitive.
- [OCDFormat](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat): also dormant, couldn't get it to install.

Comment: Can you *show* us what vertically aligning similar lines looks like?

Comment: The first link above shows it pretty well. 
 http://codealignment.com/Details.html

Comment: The Eclipse Java formatter does not only align equal signs and [can also be executed on the command line](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-231.htm).

Comment: I have looked into this myself and could not find anything for Eclipse. The only approach I know of that comes close to doing what you want is [1] Do the formatting yourself manually. [2] Be sure to use a Java formatter in Eclipse (such as Google's) which won't undo your efforts.

Comment: I see that there are 3 votes to close this question because _"This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center"_. I disagree because the Help Center explicitly states _"if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_. This question is a good fit for those criteria.

Comment: @JimK I know this is an old question, but this post [Auto-align “=” in assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13936569/2985643) might be helpful if this is still an issue for you.