# "Align Field in Columns" C/C++

Tags: eclipse, alignment

Is there a way to configure Eclipse code formatter for C/C++ to Align fields in columns

```
//without formatting
int mRect = 0;
int mSquare = 0;
bool isTriangle = false;

//to look like this???
int  mRect      = 0;
int  mSquare    = 0;
bool isTriangle = false;
```

For Java I found this
[Eclipse: Auto-align "=" in assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936569/eclipse-auto-align-in-assignments)

Comment: I answered your question, but my answer got deleted. See this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307311/395857).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with OCDFormat.jar as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18491579, and it works for C++ too.

It would be still nice if we can do this with native eclipse formatter.

Comment: OCDFormat is nice but there is an issue with some (common) operators: https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse plugin [columns4eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/) should do the trick (gratis, open source, I use it with Eclipse 4.3 x64 and 4.5 x64 on Windows 7). It is not language-dependent.

([OCDFormat](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat) is ok too though a bit less flexible and there is an [issue with some (common) operators](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/issues)).