# Eclipse c-formatter | preserve whitespaces between arg-type and arg-name in function header

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, formatter

I would like to configure the eclipse formatter to preserve whitespaces between argument type and argument name in function declarations. Does anyone know if this configuration is possible?

**what i want**

```
int testfunc ( int        a,       // testomato
               bool_t     b,       // testomato
               sometype_t blubb ); // testomato
```

**what i get**

```
int testfunc ( int a,       // testomato
               bool_t b,       // testomato
               sometype_t blubb ); // testomato
```

---

**Some toughts**

- the option to "align fields in columns" like it is possible in eclipse-jdt would be also very interesting for the eclipse-cdt version.
- the eclipse plugin columns4eclipse which could be a solution is not working for actual eclipse versions

Comment: I found a related post. See [“Align Field in Columns” C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104147/align-field-in-columns-c-c)

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution ? The OCDFormat plugin does not seem to work for the latest version of Eclipse

Comment: No I have no solution, sorry